# Fix Grid's actual with in container

Tags: wpf, xaml, width, actualwidth

Imagine we have gind in another grid , parent grid have many children , based on them our grid gets some actual width heights. All i need is to fix getted actual width as my grids  width, how can i do it?  I tried to bind width to actual width itself but result it terrible you now.

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps you can post some simplified XAML demonstrating your layout and what you want? I'm not sure I understand

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand , you want to retrieve the size of the parent without defining it, and when you do, you get an NaN value.
You have to update the layout of the Grid first, like this :

```
parentGrid.UpdateLayout();
double with = parentGrid.ActualWidth;
```

Comment: Yes something like this, but in XAML

Comment: You want the children grid to have the same width as its parent ?

Comment: I am putting in it items with drag drop, and i do not want it be resized

Comment: Can you show us some code pls ? I don't really understand what is your problem .

Comment: ok i will make example tomorrow , thanks you for your time my friend.

Comment: Can you share your solution ? It probably will be useful for someone else